# Why do we don't have hash and pred functors for a map?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, ordered-map

In case of `unordered_map` we define the `hash` and `pred` functors whenever we are using `user-defined` keys.

The template syntax for a map is as follows:

```
template < class Key,                                     // map::key_type
       class T,                                           // map::mapped_type
       class Compare = less<Key>,                         // map::key_compare
       class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> >       // map::allocator_type
       > class map;
```

In case of map there is no `hash` and `pred` functors option. Do we never have collisions in case of `map`. If collisions happen then why don't we have the `hash` and `pred` functors as in `unordered_map`?
Am I missing something here?

Comment: [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (as well as [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)) is usually implemented as a *tree*. With a tree there are no collisions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map` and `std::unordered_map` are two different types of containers that both provided key-value pair mapping.  How they do that though is completely different.

`std::map` uses a tree structure for its implementation.    Typically this is an RBTree but any tree that can guarantee worst case `O(logN)` operations will work.  This means it only needs to have a comparison operator for the key type since you can get total ordering and check for equality with a comparator that implements a strict weak ordering.  This means you'll never have a hash collision since you aren't using a hash.

`std::unordered_map` is based on a hash table implementation.  Since it hashes the key, you need a hash operator.  You also need a comparison operator since two values could hash to the same value (hash collision).  Without the comparison operator you would not be able to tell if the duplicate hash is really a duplicate item.

Answer (score 5):

`std::map` is not a hash table and thus doesn't use a hash function. Instead, it requires `operator<` for ordering the values contained in the map.